# What JWT validation do I need to do on an Identity Server Client?

Tags: identityserver3

I configured my identity server client like this in Startup.cs

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.Authority = Configuration["Urls:IdentityServer"];
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

    options.Audience = Configuration["Urls:IdentityServer"] + "/resources";
    options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
}
```

will this take of all the recommended JWT validations(signature, nonce etc) or do I have to write any validations of my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should require HTTPS on the metadata in production.

In addition to the JWT middleware, you will need to do scope validation.

Comment: Are they samples for scope validations in the IdentityServer GitHub Samples?

Comment: No need for a sample -- just check for the scope claim and value you're expecting.

Comment: If I add this to startup.cs `app.UseMiddleware<RequiredScopesMiddleware>(new List<string> { "myapi" });` will it suffice?